# Blazored Toast not showing up - Blazor Webassembly

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, toast, .net-7.0

I try to implement Toastmessages from the Blazored.Toast Library (https://github.com/Blazored)
My problem is that nothing happens if I call the ShowInfo() Method (or similar one like ShowError, ...).

My code so far:

I registered the ToastService in Program.cs

```cs
WebAssemblyHostBuilder builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.Services.AddBlazoredToast();

//... Some other Services...
Configuration = builder.Configuration;
```

My Blazor component

```html
@inject IToastService toastService

@using Blazored.Toast.Configuration;
@using Blazored.Toast.Services;


<body>
  <button class="btn btn-info" id="InfoButton" @onclick="@(() => toastService.ShowInfo("I'm an INFO message", settings => {settings.IconType = IconType.None; settings.Position = ToastPosition.BottomCenter;}))">Info Toast</button>
</body>
```

The button incl. style is looking fine but if I press the button, nothing showing up...

Am I missing a key part?

Comment: Did you do [step 4](https://github.com/Blazored/Toast#4-register-and-configure-toasts-component)? You are not mentioning it.

Comment: Oh wow, that's it. I got it wrong and take it as optional for further customization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've missed step 4 from the instructions (https://github.com/Blazored/Toast).

It says that you have to add the BlazoredToasts tag to the MainLayout.razor.

Now it should look like this:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@*And here we have the BlazoredToast Tag...*@
<BlazoredToasts />
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

Within the tag you can define some general stylesettings for the toasts like position or icontype. (More in the instructions)